# If <div id> Removed From HTML Document Then Redirect to a New Web Page

Tags: javascript, html

If a specific `<div id>` is removed from the HTML document, I want it the user to be redirected to a new web page using JavaScript.

For example:

```
<div id="credits"></div>
```

If someone removes it then users will be automatically redirected to my website.

This is to protect copyrights.

Comment: how is your content going to shared by users? html code?

Comment: If the user can remove the div, then he can remove the script too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can probably do is to just poll for the existence of that div, and redirect if it's not there.  Also, be sure to check that it's actually visible, per Philip's comment.

But of course any user can just turn this script off, so I'm really not sure it's even worth the effort.

```
setInterval(function(){
    if (!$('#credits:visible').length) window.location.href = 'wherever.com';
}, 3000);
```

Comment: the user can also set: display : none

Comment: @AdamRackis can this be done on some event rather than on a timer?

Comment: @Amitd - no, there's no event for a div being removed from the page

Comment: oh btw i noticed in the answer, the user can also remove the contents of the div (empty div) or have different content altogether.

Comment: @Amitd - he sure can.  There's really no good way to address this comprehensively.

Comment: Thanks a TON, I Was looking for the Similar sort of Script. Thanks once again

Comment: @AdamRackis Your script was working but now its not working? any idea why?

Comment: @SyedFaizanAli - no idea.  Have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: @AdamRackis I am Blogger Platform Theme Designer So I have to use this Script in Blogger. No, I am not getting any error. I have Applied Script on this Page http://droidopedia.blogspot.com/2012/12/script-applied-here.html

Comment: @SyedFaizanAli - it's possible that your blogger platform is disabling all scripts.

Comment: @AdamRackis Its not even working on Local Host :(... Nopes The other scripts are working fine

Comment: This Script is Working so it means there is some problem in your script

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
//-->
</script>

Comment: The script is fine - there's something going on in your blogger environment.  Have you tried to reproduce in just a plain html file?  Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9cdWp/1/

Comment: Yeah, i have test it in a Plain HTML DOC but it didn't work. Even the link which you have provided is not showing the correct results :(. Palm Face

Comment: @SyedFaizanAli - the script works fine - I just tested it: <html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    setInterval(function(){
        if (!$('#credits:visible').length) window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
    }, 3000);</script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

You want a MutationObserver, but it's not widely supported: http://jsfiddle.net/xNAXd/.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("credits");

new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    for(var i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) {
        var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(mutations[i].removedNodes, elem);
        if(~index) {
            alert("Deleted!");
            break;
        }
    }
}).observe(elem.parentNode, {
    childList: true
});
```

Comment: I don't want to receive a notification. I Want it to be redirect if the Div ID Doesn't exists

Comment: @Syed Faizan Ali: That's what this code does. If you remove the div, you get the alert. Instead of the alert, use a redirect.